# SEO friendly URL not working

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, rewrite, apache2

I have a folder structure like the below [www.exampe.com/distributor/index.php](http://www.exampe.com/distributor/index.php)
and I want to access the file via an SEO friendly  [www.example.com/distributer/abcinc](http://www.example.com/distributer/abcinc)
and then in the index.php want to get the value of the last segment in this case abcinc into the page as a variable

My issue is I am getting a 404 when I go to [www.example.com/distributer/abcinc](http://www.example.com/distributer/abcinc) but the page loads if I go to [www.example.com/distributer](http://www.example.com/distributer)

Here is my .htaccess file which lives in the distributor folder

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^distributor/([0-9]+)$ distributor/index.php?id=$1
```

I confirmed via phpinfo() that mod_rewrite is all setup/enabled so not sure what I am missing?

Comment: "distribut**o**r" or "distribut**e**r"?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ...my .htaccess file which lives **in the distributor folder**
>
> ```
> RewriteRule ^distributor/([0-9]+)$ distributor/index.php?id=$1
> ```

If the `.htaccess` file is actually inside the `/distributor` directory then you should not be referencing the `distributor` directory in the `RewriteRule` *pattern*. This matches against a URL-path that is relative to the directory that contains the `.htaccess` file.

Likewise, you should not include the `distributor` directory in a relative *substitution* string when inside the `/distributor` directory. A relative *substitution* is again relative to the directory that contains the `.htaccess` file.

Your existing `.htaccess` file is written as if it was located in the document root directory, not the `/distributor` subdirectory as stated.

However, you are also referencing both "distribut**o**r" and "distribut**e**r" in your examples - I assume the "e" is a typo, but this will obviously also result in a failed match.

And, as mentioned in @TeroKilkanen's answer, you are matching digits in your regex, not letters, as in your example URL.

So, your existing rule is matching a URL of the form `/distributor/distributor/123` and rewriting to `/distributor/distributor/index.php?id=123`.

Try the following instead, in the `/distributor/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteRule ^(\w+)$ index.php?id=$1 [L]
```

The `\w` shorthand character class matches both digits and letters and is equivalent to the character class `[0-9a-zA-Z_]`.

Answer (score 2):

Your `RewriteRule` matches only numbers, that is, `distributor/3728` etc. It does not match `abcinc`.

From the `id` argument passed to `index.php` it looks like your application expects an ID here and not a name. You need to check your application how to set it up to handle names.

Comment: even if I make the url be https://warrantycenter.cross.com/distributor/12 it gives me a 404. Although I will change it to [a-z]